# Browse my Json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following Json object in my script:

```
var antennas = 'antennas [ :{"id":"66175", "nom_com":"PARIS-8E-ARRONDISSEMENT", "nom_dept":"PARIS", "nom_reg":"ILE-DE-FRANCE", "generation":"2G", "emr_lb_systeme":"GSM 900", "coordonnes":["48.8663888889","2.32305555556"], "coord":"48° 51′ 59"N 2° 19′ 23"E"},{"id":"66176", "nom_com":"PARIS-8E-ARRONDISSEMENT", "nom_dept":"PARIS", "nom_reg":"ILE-DE-FRANCE", "generation":"4G", "emr_lb_systeme":"LTE 800", "coordonnes":["48.8663888889","2.32305555556"], "coord":"48° 51′ 59"N 2° 19′ 23"E"}]';
```

And I would like to iterate on each element.

I did this code :

```
var antennas = 'antennas [ :{"id":"66175", "nom_com":"PARIS-8E-ARRONDISSEMENT", "nom_dept":"PARIS", "nom_reg":"ILE-DE-FRANCE", "generation":"2G", "emr_lb_systeme":"GSM 900", "coordonnes":["48.8663888889","2.32305555556"], "coord":"48° 51′ 59"N 2° 19′ 23"E"},{"id":"66176", "nom_com":"PARIS-8E-ARRONDISSEMENT", "nom_dept":"PARIS", "nom_reg":"ILE-DE-FRANCE", "generation":"4G", "emr_lb_systeme":"LTE 800", "coordonnes":["48.8663888889","2.32305555556"], "coord":"48° 51′ 59"N 2° 19′ 23"E"}]';
var antennasMap = JSON.parse(antennas);

for (var key in antennasMap) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

But the console givbe me this error :

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: That isn't a valid structure. Where does it come from? Need to fix source

Comment: That string doesn't contain JSON. What is your question?

Comment: It's generally a good idea to use **dummy** data here if no semantics is damaged. Cyber security is no joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON string had multiple issues so couldn't been parsed into an javascript object:

- format of the brackets was wrong
- the string contained unescaped quotation marks in the coords string

I used http://jsonlint.com/ to find and fix the problems

Here's a valid JSON string close to what you had:

```
var antennas = '{"antennas":[{"id":"66175","nom_com":"PARIS-8E-ARRONDISSEMENT","nom_dept":"PARIS","nom_reg":"ILE-DE-FRANCE","generation":"2G","emr_lb_systeme":"GSM 900","coordonnes":["48.8663888889","2.32305555556"],"coord":"48° 51′ 59\\"N 2° 19′ 23\\"E"},{"id":"66176","nom_com":"PARIS-8E-ARRONDISSEMENT","nom_dept":"PARIS","nom_reg":"ILE-DE-FRANCE","generation":"4G","emr_lb_systeme":"LTE 800","coordonnes":["48.8663888889","2.32305555556"],"coord":"48° 51′ 59\\" N 2° 19′ 23\\"E"}]}'
```

Which resolves to this javascript object:

```
{
    "antennas": [{
        "id": "66175",
        "nom_com": "PARIS-8E-ARRONDISSEMENT",
        "nom_dept": "PARIS",
        "nom_reg": "ILE-DE-FRANCE",
        "generation": "2G",
        "emr_lb_systeme": "GSM 900",
        "coordonnes": ["48.8663888889", "2.32305555556"],
        "coord": "48° 51′ 59\"N 2° 19′ 23\"E"
    }, {
        "id": "66176",
        "nom_com": "PARIS-8E-ARRONDISSEMENT",
        "nom_dept": "PARIS",
        "nom_reg": "ILE-DE-FRANCE",
        "generation": "4G",
        "emr_lb_systeme": "LTE 800",
        "coordonnes": ["48.8663888889", "2.32305555556"],
        "coord": "48° 51′ 59\"N 2° 19′ 23\"E"
    }]
}
```

Here is a sample code which outputs the records to the console.

```js
var antennas = '{"antennas":[{"id":"66175","nom_com":"PARIS-8E-ARRONDISSEMENT","nom_dept":"PARIS","nom_reg":"ILE-DE-FRANCE","generation":"2G","emr_lb_systeme":"GSM 900","coordonnes":["48.8663888889","2.32305555556"],"coord":"48° 51′ 59\\"N 2° 19′ 23\\"E"},{"id":"66176","nom_com":"PARIS-8E-ARRONDISSEMENT","nom_dept":"PARIS","nom_reg":"ILE-DE-FRANCE","generation":"4G","emr_lb_systeme":"LTE 800","coordonnes":["48.8663888889","2.32305555556"],"coord":"48° 51′ 59\\"N 2° 19′ 23\\"E"}]}';

var antennasMap = JSON.parse(antennas);

antennasMap.antennas.forEach (function (record) {
  console.log(record);
})
```

Comment: My problem was about the " inside my string ?

Comment: Yes, and also the beginning of the string was not legal json: `antennas [ :{"id"...`